# Simple SQLite query not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite compact edition,I done some tests using linqdpad, worked fine. But when I go to C# code, it not works. I tried get fields from database with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conStr = @"data source=C:\path\db.sdf;password=...";
            var con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select * from quest", con);
            SqlCeDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Console.Write(result.Read());
            Console.ReadLine();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

`result.Read()` returns `false`. as if had not fields. how I fix it?

Using linqpad I can see something like:

[image]

query:

```
select * from quest;
```

**UPDATE**
The problem happens when the database(.sdf) uses a password.

Comment: Hopefully you are closing the connection in code below this.  Consider using a `using` for that.  Can you please post the linqpad query you use to give you the results you posted.

Comment: @AdamWenger:Added full code. and linqpad query/output.

Answer (score 0):

check the semicolon in the end of your query.maybe by delete it your query execute right.
in other hand every thing is correct generally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks alright to me - maybe this:

```
var result
```

Change it to SqlCeDataReader. Its the only 'mistake' I can see.

Also don't forget to close the connection after you're done.

Comment: I think the problem is not here. Basically,the compiler convert 'var' to your real type in compilation. And yeah, I closed the connection in my "real" code.